# Lookup transformation between DB2 packed decimal and SQL Server DT_NUMERIC in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, db2, etl

We use DB2 as our main production database, but we use SQL Server for many other things i.e. to do integration between other customers and vendors via EDI etc.
I have a table in SQL with SO numbers and I try to make a lookup in DB2 to get all the invoices for the SO's in my table, so here's what I did.

1. Created a connection to the DB2 using the [Microsoft® OLEDB Provider for DB2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29100)
2. Created a [data fllow](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122.aspx) with a source using a SQL Server connection.
3. Added a [Data Conversion Transformation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141706.aspx) trying to convert the INT so value to a decimal with a precision of 12, but I couldn't change a precision in a DT_DECIMAL, so the only datatype that I have the option to change the precision is DT_NUMERIC.
4. Added a lookup transformation to lookup the data withing DB2.

Now when i try to create the join between the source table and DB2 I get an error `Cannot map the input column, 'so', to the lookup column, 'orno', because the data types do not match.`
[According to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/477262/ssis-flat-file-connection-manager-cannot-set-precision-for-decimal-columns) this is not a bug and they suggest to use the DT_NUMERIC where you can change the precision.
If I try to convert the SO to a DT_DECIMAL without changing the precision I'd get the same error mentioned above.

Is there any way to work around the limitations from SSIS and change the precision in a DT_DECIMAL conversion so I could do the match?

Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to change the connection property in the DB2 connection to treat DECIMAL as NUMERIC.
See bellow 
[image]